# Segfault at sem_post

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, semaphore

I am trying to write a small C program using semaphores, but I am having this issue I can't resolve. I am always getting a segfault at sem_post.
Here is the relevant part of the main method in my server code:

```
sem_t * sem_query = NULL;
sem_t * sem_server = NULL;
sem_t * sem_client = NULL;

//prepare semaphores
init_semaphores(sem_query, sem_server, sem_client);

//prepare the shared memory
struct shm_struct * shared = init_shm();
int exit_code = 0;

while (1) {

    if (sem_post(sem_query) == -1) {
        perror("Error posting the semaphore!");
        exit_code = 1;
        break;
    }

    if (sem_wait(sem_server) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            printf("Received interrupting signal! Quitting now...");
            break;
        } else {
            perror("Error while waiting on semaphore!");
            exit_code = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    //calculate the response and write it to shm
    calculate_and_write_response(shared, procs);

    if (sem_post(sem_client) == -1) {
        perror("Error posting the semaphore!");
        exit_code = 1;
        break;
    }

     if (sem_wait(sem_server) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            printf("Received interrupting signal! Quitting now...");
            break;
        } else {
            perror("Error while waiting on semaphore!");
            exit_code = 1;
            break;
        }
    } 

}    
free_shm(shared);

free_semaphores(sem_query, sem_server, sem_client);

exit(exit_code);
```

And here is the init_semaphores method:

```
static void init_semaphores(sem_t * s1, sem_t * s2, sem_t * s3) {

    s1 = sem_open(SEM_A_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);
    s2 = sem_open(SEM_B_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);
    s3 = sem_open(SEM_C_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);

    if (s1 == SEM_FAILED || s2 == SEM_FAILED || s3 == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("Could not open semaphores!");
        free_semaphores(s1, s2, s3);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I am not posting the code for the client thread here because it is irrelevant: The segfault occures immediately after I start the server, without the client process running. None of my error messages is printed before the segfault.

Here is the what gdb says when running the program:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff79c6b44 in sem_post@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64
```

So, if I am reading this correctly, the segfault occures at a sem_post() call, which has to be the first call on sem_query, because the program would wait at the sem_wait() call.

What is wrong with the code? Where does the segfault come from?

Comment: Looking at it, you're `free_semaphores` when they're `NULL` and is failing when trying to open the semaphores via `sem_open`. Have you double checked that they are indeed being opened?

Comment: @t0mm13b I already tried removing the line `free_semaphores(s1, s2, s3);` which doesn't change anything

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I did. GCC with -Wall -pedantic, there was not a single warning

Comment: @SimMac: oops, sorry. Thought that was a library function. To lazy to read..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initialization of semaphores isn't right:

```
init_semaphores(sem_query, sem_server, sem_client);
```

The function `init_semaphores` would only modify the local copies (`s1`, `s2` and `s3`). So the changes in `init_semaphores()` do not change the pointers in main(), leaving your semaphores set to NULL. Instead pass pointer to pointers to modify them:

```
//prepare semaphores
init_semaphores(&sem_query, &sem_server, &sem_client);
```

and

```
static void init_semaphores(sem_t **s1, sem_t **s2, sem_t **s3) {

    *s1 = sem_open(SEM_A_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);
    *s2 = sem_open(SEM_B_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);
    *s3 = sem_open(SEM_C_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);

    if (*s1 == SEM_FAILED || *s2 == SEM_FAILED || *s3 == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("Could not open semaphores!");
        free_semaphores(*s1, *s2, *s3);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I am still not very familiar with pointers, they are still a new concept to me.

Comment: You haven't shown the `free_semaphores()`. Make sure it can handle if arg(s) are NULL. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I did that after t0mm1b 's comment. Thank you! :)